# Why am I getting a missing Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure exception when running Powershell in a .NET Core app?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

We have a simple .NET Core console application that is attempting to use Powershell. We are trying to run this app on a Windows Server 2019 VM.

It works as expected when run through Visual Studio 2022 on a 2019 VM.

We created a ClickOnce (self-contained) publish profile to install/test it on other Windows 2019 server VMs.

When running via the ClickOnce install, we get an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> Third exception at close:
> Could not load file or assembly  'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Here are the NuGet packages for the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.3.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is the sample code snippet:

```
PowerShell? psInstance = null;

try
{
    psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
    psInstance.AddScript(@"Get-Service");
    var results = psInstance.Invoke();

    if (!results.Any() && psInstance.HadErrors)
    {
        // Display Error Text
    }

    psInstance.Runspace?.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"First exception: {e.Message}");

        if (psInstance?.Runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
        {
            psInstance?.Runspace?.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Second exception at close: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

It feels like we are missing some dlls/packages that should be included as part of the deployment?

I thought adding the package through NuGet would also install any additionally required dependencies.

Comment: Not sure here, but in other uses of PowerShell, it doesn't work in a `.NET Standard 2.1` world, but it does in a `.NET Standard 2.0` world. Try putting your PS code in a separate assembly targeting 2.0, and then consume it in your console app - see what happens

Comment: Also, is your project targeting `net8.0`? `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` version `7.3.x` and its dependency tree brings in `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure 2.0.0` which doesn't seem to play well with `net8.0`.

Comment: Is that the error from the powershell script itself, or an error on the .net app, thats trying to run the powershell?

Comment: @KG-DROID - The error is from the .NetCore app trying to run the script.

Comment: Is it definitely that snippet of code that's causing the error, as I've made a project that literally just has that snippet in along with `using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;`, and it doesn't error for me. My project is targeted at .net 7, target OS: Windows.

Comment: @KG-DROID - when I ran through VS, it worked fine. When I ran it on a newly created Windows Server 2019 VM it generated the error.

Comment: Is standard PowerShell 5 installed and not blocked on the server, just in case there is a common dependency?

Comment: @KG-DROID - Not sure I follow, can you explain more? Do you mean Powershell 5 (not .Net Powershell). It's my understanding that those are 2 separate entities, behave differently and don't interact.

Comment: They are separate entities as far as I know, but I'm not sure if they share any dependencies, as I've never tried PS7 on a device that didn't have, or had PS5 blocked. That dll its complaining is missing is here: `C:\Windows\WinSxS\msil_microsoft.management.infrastructure_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_e95d243bac30b5e1\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll` in my Windows Install, so it does seem like its either part of non Server Windows, or maybe part of PS5. I suppose you could try adding a reference to it in your project, if its missing from the server OS.